# Add usercontrol directly in Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, control-library

Is it proper to add usercontrol directly in Windows Form Application instead of creating Windows Form Control Library and reference it to Windows Form Application?

Comment: Don't hesitate to just *try* this.

Comment: I already tried it I'm just asking if its proper or is there any issue about it. :)

Comment: There's nothing improper about it, there are no "issues".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes; that is perfectly possible.

You will still need to rebuild the project to make the designer pick up changes in the control.